# Does remote working for a US Company qualify you for a SSN?

Tags: contracts, usa, remote

I worked for a few months as a contractor (from India) for a US company. I was located in India the entire time.

While applying for a regular job in India, the Indian company is asking for my US Social Security Number.

Is it required for an individual to apply for a SSN or EIN, or something else in this case, or for US-based companies you work for remotely to give you a SSN?

If not, then how should I explain this to my new job? This was my first remote contract, so I'm worried I may be in trouble over this.

Comment: You mean social security number? And who is asking for it, your Indian employer or the US company? An Indian employer should be asking for your indian SSN, not a US one. You don't get a US SSN for working a remote contract job: you would need to live and work in the US to get one.

Comment: @user3244085 Indian company is asking for US SSN.. I think that there is some misinformation with my new company that i went to US for contract. Telling them, that i worked from India only should solve the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no you do not need a SSN. You will not be able to even apply for a SSN since you did not mention you have a visa to work **physically in the US**.

The most common request for a SSN for an overseas contractor to a US company is for the W-8 forms. The IRS says these are for "[non-resident aliens who do work and/or make income in the U.S. or foreign business entities who make income in the U.S](https://www.irs.com/articles/fill-out-irs-tax-form-w-8)".

Without these forms, the US company is obligated to withhold a percentage of your funds. On the most common W-8BEN form, you have the option of entering your SSN or ITIN (Individual Taxpayer Identification Number). However this is optional, see [the instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf) to decide if you need to apply for an ITIN.

It sounds like there is some miscommunication with your Indian company. You should explain you do not need a SSN and that you were not working physically in the US.

Comment: Do note that the US company is only obligated to withold taxes on us-sourced income. Counterintutively, this is *not* us-sourced income in this case, because the income source is tied to the contractor location. (see https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/nonresident-aliens-source-of-income). In the case of personal business services, income is only us-sourced if the work is physically performed in the USA. As such, NO witholding tax is necessary and NO W-8BEN is required. If this person were to travel to the USA and work there for a few weeks, then they'd need this paperwork.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not need a U.S. SSN.

You can find all of the official information about U.S. SSN (Social Security Numbers) in this pdf-document published by the U.S. Social Security office.

[Social Security Numbers for Noncitizens](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10096.pdf)